# Graphic elments fall apart after installed new RAM

Tags: unity, graphics, ram

I have installed a new RAM module and after that the graphics elements in Unity are started to fall apart. (See attachment.) In some applications this problem appear, but non in others (ad.: in Chrome).

I ran the memtest but it didn't show errors.

I have 2x2GB Hynix memory and now I installed a 2GB Nanya.

Under Windows this error isn't appear at all.

(I use Ubuntu 15.10.)

How can I fix this problem? :)

[image: Picture of the dekstop]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: I reinstalled Unity.